# Laravel Auth Custom Driver Error

Tags: authentication, laravel, driver

FYI : I'm very new to Laravel and doing my best to learn it properly.
Working on an auth driver that uses a soap service to authenticate.
Error I get when trying to test with Auth::attempt()

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_COMPILE_ERROR) 
Declaration of Project\Providers\AuthUserProvider::retrieveByToken() must be compatible with Illuminate\Auth\UserProviderInterface::retrieveByToken($identifier, $token)
```

Here is the driver...

```
<?php namespace Project\Providers;

use Illuminate\Auth\UserProviderInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;

class AuthUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface {
    /**
  * External webservice for authentication
  */
  private $webservice;
   /**
  * The user object.
  */
  private $user;

    /**
  * Constructor
  *
  * @return void
  */
  public function __construct(\Project\Webservice\AuthCheckApi $webservice)
  {
      $this->webservice = $webservice;
      $this->user = null;
  }


    /**
  * Retrieves a user by id
  *
  * @param int $identifier
  * @return mixed null|array
  */
  public function retrieveByID($identifier)
  {
      $this->user = is_null($this->user) ? $this->webservice->find($identifier) : $this->user;
      return $this->user;
  }

    /**
  * Tries to find a user based on the credentials passed.
  *
  * @param array $crendtials username|password
  * @return mixed bool|UserInterface
  */
  public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
  {
      if(!$user = $this->webservice->byusername($credentials['username'],$credentials['password'])) return false;

      return new GenericUser($user);
  }

      /**
     * Validates the credentials passed to the ones in webservice.
     *
     * @param UserInterface $user
     * @param array $credentials
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validateCredentials(\Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface $user, array $credentials)
    {
       $validated = $this->webservice->validateCredentials($user,$credentials['username']);

      return true;
    }

      /**
   * Needed by Laravel 4.1.26 and above
   */
  public function retrieveByToken()
  {
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * Needed by Laravel 4.1.26 and above
   */
  public function updateRememberToken()
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are implementing the UserProviderInterface so you need to add the complete definition of all functions of the interface, here you are forgetting the arguments for the last two function

```
public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token)
{

}

 public function updateRememberToken($user, $token)
{

}
```